# thinking sphinx: syntax error in date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :offer, :with => :active_record do

  indexes tags(:name), as: :tags
  indexes :name, as: :offer_name
  indexes :description, as: :offer_description

  has enabled, as: :offer_enabled

  has customer.is_enabled, as: :customer_enabled
  has customer.is_accepted, as: :customer_accepted

  has category.id, as: :category_id
  has :to, as: offer_to

end
```

Now when making a search and using a Date range for an attribute like

```
Offer.search( 'some search terms', with: { to: Date.current..(Date.current + 12.months), category_id: 3 } )
```

I get the following error message:

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting AND near '-12-27 AND 2014-12-27 AND `category_id` = 9 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 50; SHOW META'
```

I am using:

sphinx version 2.1.3 
thinking sphinx version 3.0.6
rails 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed within the Thinking Sphinx issues on Github, but for others coming across this and wondering what the fix is:

The issue is the dates in the filter - Thinking Sphinx (or rather, Riddle, the underlying Ruby gem for interacting with Sphinx) doesn't convert dates to integer timestamps, which is how Sphinx stores time (and thus date) data.

The quick fix is to use times or integer timestamp instead, but the next release of Riddle will include a patch that automatically converts dates to integer timestamps in filters (v1.5.10).